# meaning of $(this) in an if(){}

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this rule:

```
if($('fieldset[data-input-type=checkbox]').find('input').is(':checked'))
{
    alert($(this));
}
```

why do I get "object Object" as an alert and not the fieldset? How would I do a specific action for each fieldset with a checked input in it and not all of them?

Comment: In what context do you run this code?

Comment: How else would the fieldset be represented, if not as an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
$('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hVTBF/

---

or if you indeed have to filter only to `fieldset` that have the attribute `data-input-type` then use

```
$('fieldset[data-input-type=checkbox]:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

---

**Update** *after comment*

Since you just want to run more jQuery methods on the objects you can directly do that in your initial selector and avoid the `each` which runs a function for each item.

```
$('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked) .switch').add‌​‌​Class('on');
```

and

```
$('fieldset:not(:has(:checkbox:checked)) .switch').add‌​‌​Class('off');
```

Comment: so, if I want to replace if and else this would do it I think: $('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){$(this).find('.switch').add‌​Class('on')}); $('fieldset:not(:has(:checkbox:checked))').each(function(){$(this).find('.switc‌​h').addClass('off')});

Comment: @Snippet, i updated answer with a shorter and simpler code for what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery v1.6 [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)  method

```
if($('input:checkbox').prop('checked'))
{
    alert('This is checked');
}
```